# how to initialize parent template's properties in emberjs controller?

Tags: templates, ember.js, properties, controller

Assuming that I have parent application template and in it's outlet there is users template. Now when I load users route, I want to change properties of application template too, which are outside of user's scope. How can I modify application properties from users controller??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `controllerFor` in the `setupController` hook in your user route:

```
UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    @_super(controller, model)

    @controllerFor('application').set('foo', 'bar')
```

You could also check out [the needs API](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you please provide an example usage for `needs` as well?